# Pinch Zoom on Image but ImageView does not change size

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom

Edit: Alternatively, if anybody has any other methods of implementing pinch zoom it would be really helpful.

In my project I have several ImageViews on a page each needs to be able to be zoomed individually. I have so far been using this code to controll the zooming

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 0f;
float maxScale = 2f;
float[] m;

float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

float width, height;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

TouchImageView thisImageView = this;


public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                    float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                    float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                    if (scaleWidth < width) {
                        deltaX = 0;
                        if (y + deltaY > 0)
                            deltaY = -y;
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom); 
                    } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                        deltaY = 0;
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                    } else {
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);

                        if (y + deltaY > 0)
                            deltaY = -y;
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                    }
                    matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                    performClick();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            }
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

public void setImageDrawable(Drawable dr) { 
    super.setImageDrawable(dr);
    bmWidth = dr.getIntrinsicWidth();
    bmHeight = dr.getIntrinsicHeight();
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x)
{
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = (float)Math.min(Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right) 
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0) 
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }


        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right) 
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0) 
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }

        }
        return true;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    System.out.println(widthMeasureSpec + "  " + heightMeasureSpec);

    int  w = (int) bmWidth;
    int  h = (int) bmHeight;
    width = resolveSize(w, widthMeasureSpec);  
    height = resolveSize(h, heightMeasureSpec);

    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX =  (float)width / (float)bmWidth;
    float scaleY = (float)height / (float)bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = (float)height - (scale * (float)bmHeight) ;
    redundantXSpace = (float)width - (scale * (float)bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float)2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

}

Which works but when I pinch zoom on the ImageView only the Image inside grows and shrinks in the size. The actual ImageView stays the same size meaning it will often go off the edges of the ImageView and become invisible.

So far I've tried many different methods of using pinch zoom as well as using:

```
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

To try to force the ImageView to change size.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Touch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    String extStorageDirectory;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    static final int ROTATE = 3;
    static final int ROTATES = 4;
    int mode = NONE;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    int r = 0;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    Bitmap bm;
    int fCount = 0;

    File _photoFile;
    Uri _fileUri;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);


        showImage();

        // ...
        // Work around a Cupcake bug
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);



    float[] lastEvent = null;
    float d = 0f;
    float newRot = 0f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
        WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(rawEvent);
        // ...
        // Dump touch event to log
        dumpEvent(event);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        // Dump touch event to log
        dumpEvent(event);
        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            // matrix.postRotate(90);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                // ...
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                        - start.y);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "Count=" + event.getPointerCount());
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

                }
                if (lastEvent != null) {
                    newRot = rotation(event);
                    Log.d("Dgereeee", "newRot=" + (newRot));
                    float r = newRot - d;
                    matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                            view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                }
            }
            break;

        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(WrapMotionEvent event) {
        // ...
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(
                    action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
    }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(WrapMotionEvent event) {
        // ...
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Determine the degree between the first two fingers */
    private float rotation(WrapMotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        Log.d("Rotation ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", delta_x + " ## " + delta_y + " ## "
                + radians + " ## " + Math.toDegrees(radians));
        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, WrapMotionEvent event) {
        // ...
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }


}
```

and in your xml use scale type as matrix

```
android:scaleType="matrix"
```

Comment: Im not entirely sure how I would be able to work this into my code.

Comment: But what exactly are oldDist, savedMatrix and lastEvent? And spacing()?

Comment: If its possibe would you be able to post all of your code in its entirety?

Comment: I still have a lot of unknown variables in this new method? Just the entire class file would be great.

Comment: What are those unknown variables? That class has many other different methods, can't share the entire class.

Comment: Pretty much all of the method really. Can you not just share the sections of code that are relevent to pinch zoom?

Comment: Thats not working me at all now :/. Any ideas? Thanks for all your help so far though.

Comment: Ah no sorry, it is working now but it is still going outside of its borders all give you an example in a moment.

Comment: This is how it looks before any scaling: (See the green image) http://i45.tinypic.com/1g413n.jpg

And after scaling
http://i48.tinypic.com/fzbuxd.jpg

As you can see the imageview stays the same size but the image gets larger and so it cannot be seen properly.

Comment: How do you mean? Could you exaplain what you mean?

Comment: Alright. Just add **case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN** to your code.

Comment: I already have that in there, my code now looks almost identical to yours.

Comment: @Numair can you tell me when I put scaleType Matrix in xml My image start looking on the top left corner of the screen where as I wanted it to show on the bottom of the scree. Well through your code at least it working but tell me if you can solve my problem.